# how to implement comparison of two products on ng-click in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to call same api with different product id so i can compare two product details , how i can send two different id to same api .

Here is my click function with

```
<div class="hmpal-prprt-post-wdgt hmpal-prprt-compare" 
 ng-click="compareProjects(project.property_id)" 
 ng-repeat="project in properties"><a href="">
 <span class="prprt-icon">
  <i class="fa fa-balance-scale" aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </span>
 <span>Compare</span></a>
```

Comment: what do you mean by *how i can send two different id to same api?*

Comment: Can you please elaborate your issue and if possible can you create a demo?

Comment: Show us your angular code. Can't really help, if you don't show what have you done towards solving your problem. Also, you can send two different api requests with two different ids at the same api address. For more, please read the documents for the particular api.

Comment: I want to compare two product(like mobile comparison in Flipcart) so i can do it in angular and node server

Comment: pass the two products id in single request, and then you process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand your requirement. You want to compare 2 items chosen by the user, let's say your have items A,B,C,D and the user can choose to compare B and D.

This is actually more of a UI/UX problem instead of programming problem.

This is one of the designs I can think of

```js
angular.module('test', []).controller('Test', TestController);

function TestController($scope) {
  $scope.items = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
  $scope.selected1 = "";
  $scope.selected2 = "";
  $scope.compare = "";
  
  $scope.select = function(item) {
    // first select
    if (!$scope.selected1) {
      $scope.selected1 = item;
      return;
    }
    
    // second select
    if (!$scope.selected2) {
      if ($scope.selected1 == item) {
        $scope.selected1 = "";
        return;
      }
      else {
        $scope.selected2 = item;
        compare();
        return;
      }
    }
    
    // back to first select again
    $scope.selected1 = item;
    $scope.selected2 = "";
  }
  
  function compare() {
    $scope.compare = "comparing '" + $scope.selected1 + "' and '" + $scope.selected2 + "'";
  }
}
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <div ng-repeat="item in items"
       ng-class="{'selected': item == selected1 || item == selected2}"
       ng-click="select(item)">
    {{item}}
  </div>
  <br>
  <div>{{compare}}</div>
</div>
```